# Replacement for static classes to pack methods and variables

Tags: c#

I'm creating an app that includes many "tests". Each test has a name, description and some code to run.

I want to have a list (ObservableCollection) of tests name to show in a ListBox. When user clicks on a test, the description should appear in a text box and when the user clicks start button, the related method should start.

I decided to put each test in a static class with "Name" and "description" properties and a "Test" method. But listing the classes is hard (tried using `Assembly.GetTypes()` but it's a little hard). Also manually creating a list of methods or classes is not a good way. I think there should be a better way to my goal.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: What have these test classes in common? How do you identify that the class is a test class and not a class for something else?

Comment: Can you show some of these test classes with sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is that you have decided to make these classes static? You could have these as normal normal classes.

You could have a interface such as ITestable

```
public interface ITestable
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    string Description {get;set;}
    Task Test();
}
```

1. Now you could search for classes that implement the interface using reflection.
2. From the list of classes you could filter the classes that are not abstract
3. Then you could still filter and get the classes that have a no argument constructor

Now using reflection, you could instantiate the classes to get objects

`var testable = (ITestable) Activator.CreateInstance(filteredClassType);`

I hope this helps you. If not feel free to clarify, I have done exactly the same thing in my project.

Comment: Thanks. I can't test this solution right now. I'll test it later and accept as solution if it worked. I decided to use static classes to be able to use them without creating an instance of them.

Comment: "I have done exactly the same thing in my project." is your project open source? Could you please post a code example or your project? I really need a code example! I'm new to OOP languages.

Comment: Something: `Test();` should be a method (in my case `string Test();`) not a Task. Because it should return some value.

Comment: Then I would suggest Task<string>. Retuning a string would work, but could freeze the UI

Comment: I'll work on using task later. Because `Test();` calls a method in MainWindow class and it makes things a little complex. What about code example? I really need it! :)

Comment: I did this in the previous project. So need to code. That will take some time about a day or 2. If you implement and share the link in GitHub, I can fix things for you

Comment: Thank you. But I prefer not to publish my project now. I just need a simplified example of code. I'll wait until you write it!

Comment: I leave it to you... You could publish a simplified code if you wish. Else I can send you the code sample when I get free

Comment: ok. Please send the code sample when you get free. I'll wait...

Answer (score 1):

I also post my code example:

```
List<Type> Types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Tester.Tests").ToList();
//Creates a list of all classes in "Tester.Tests" namespace

foreach (Type item in Types)
{
    TestsList.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(item));
}
//Creates an instance (object) of each class in Types

TestNames = new ObservableCollection<string>(); //Initialized before

//Note that all classes in "Tester.Test" implemented "ITest" interface
foreach (ITest item in TestsList)
{
    ُTestNames.Add(item.Name);
}
```